# Can I set end date as only one cell to it's specific end date in FullCalendar?

Tags: angular, typescript, object, fullcalendar, momentjs

In FullCalendarJS, we all know that having a long event displays an extended horizontal bar in the calendar. What I wanted to do is show the start date in only 1 cell as well as the end date. I can already do the start date, but the end date cannot be move to it's desired cell/date. For example, please screenshot image below:

[image]

The Start Date is March 26, 2021, while End Date should be March 30, 2021.

Here's my typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import { CalendarService } from '@services/calendar.service';
import { CALENDAR_FILTERS } from '@shared/constants';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import moment from 'moment';

const MINI = 'mini-calendar';
const FULL = 'full-calendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    calendarFilters: any;
    calendar: Calendar;
    isLoading: boolean;

    @Input() eventSource: (startDate: any, endDate: any, callback: any, filters: any) => any;
    @Input() withFilters: boolean;
    @Input() appearance: string;
    @Output() onDateClick = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() onEventClick = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private calendarService: CalendarService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.withFilters) {
            this.calendarService.fetchCalendarFilters().subscribe((res) => {
                this.calendarFilters = res.calendar_filter
                    ? JSON.parse(res.calendar_filter.config)
                    : CALENDAR_FILTERS.slice(0);
                this.initializeCalendar();
                this.addCalendarFiltersSection();
            });

            return;
        }

        this.initializeCalendar();
    }

    initializeCalendar() {
        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('common-calendar');
        this.calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
            header: {
                left: this.appearance == MINI ? 'title' : '',
                center: this.appearance == MINI ? '' : 'title',
                right: 'prev, today, next'
            },
            eventSources: [this.fetchEvents.bind(this)],
            dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this),
            eventClick: this.eventClick.bind(this),
            displayEventEnd: true,
            eventTimeFormat: { 
                hour: 'numeric',
                minute: '2-digit',
                meridiem: 'short'
            },
            eventRender: function(info) {
                let el = info.el;
                let data = info.event;
                el.childNodes[0].remove();

                let title = document.createElement("p");
                var bold = document.createElement("strong");
                title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.title));
                title.classList.add("cstm-fc-title");
                el.appendChild(title);  

                let time = document.createElement("p");
                let start = moment(data.start).format('hh:mm A');
                let end = moment(data.end).add(1, 'days').format('hh:mm A');
                time.appendChild(document.createTextNode(start.concat(' - ', end)));
                time.classList.add("cstm-fc-time");
                el.appendChild(time);   
            },
            eventPositioned: function(info) {
                let el = info.el;
                if (info.event.extendedProps.event_type === 'placed') {
                    el.parentElement.removeAttribute("colspan");
                    el.parentElement.setAttribute("colspan", "1");
                } 
            }
        });
        this.calendar.render();
    }


    refetchEvents() {
        this.calendar.refetchEvents();
    }

    fetchEvents(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        this.eventSource(info.startStr, info.endStr, successCallback, this.calendarFilters);
    }

    dateClick(info) {
        this.onDateClick.emit(info)
    }

    eventClick(info) {
        this.onEventClick.emit(info);
    }

    onCalendarFilterClick(event) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const calendar_event = event.target.id;

        this.calendarFilters.includes(calendar_event)
            ? this.calendarFilters.splice(this.calendarFilters.indexOf(calendar_event), 1)
            : this.calendarFilters.push(calendar_event);

        this.calendarService.setCalendarFilters({ config: this.calendarFilters }).subscribe(calendar => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
        this.generateButtonEventFilters(this.calendarFilters);
        this.calendar.refetchEvents();
    }

    setLoader(value) {
        this.isLoading = value;
    }

    private addCalendarFiltersSection() {
        var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.fc-view-container');
        let html = '<div class="btn-group-events" id="custom-buttons"></div>';

        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
        this.generateButtonEventFilters(this.calendarFilters);
    }

    private generateButtonEventFilters(calendarFilters) {
        let buttons = '';

        CALENDAR_FILTERS.forEach(function (event, index) {
            buttons += `<button type="button" id="${event}" class="${
                calendarFilters.includes(event) ? 'btn-event' : 'btn-event btn-event-active'
            }">
        ${event.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + event.substring(1)}</button>`;
        });

        document.getElementById('custom-buttons').innerHTML = buttons;
        this.addHandlers();
    }

    private addHandlers() {
        CALENDAR_FILTERS.forEach((calendar_event) => {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${calendar_event}`).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                this.onCalendarFilterClick(event);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you splitting a single event into two boxes? I wasn't quite sure what your intention was. Also we can see the event data coming from `this.eventSource` please? It's a bit confusing without that information. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was. The this.eventSource is already providing the correct data. It is from a service we've made @ADyson

Comment: Ok I'm not saying the event source is wrong, I'm saying I need to see what it returns in order to relate it to your screenshot and then try to understand how we might resolve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry @ADyson. Okay, uhm, I have already resolved it. Thank you. I'll add the fix here.

Answer (score 1):

So I've fixed the issue and my workaround was to manipulate the endDate using `VanillaJS` and some FullCalendar's `event` callbacks.

Here's the final look:

[image]

I've used the `eventRender` and `eventPositioned` callbacks, and then check on the console on what `info` object was returning. From there, I manipulated it combining with some **Vanilla JS**.

```
eventRender: function(info) {
        let el = info.el;
        let data = info.event;
        el.childNodes[0].remove();

        let title = document.createElement("p");
        title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.title));
        title.classList.add("cstm-fc-title");
        el.appendChild(title);

        let time = document.createElement("p");
        let start = moment(data.start).format('hh:mm A');
        let end = moment(data.end).add(1, 'days').format('hh:mm A');
        time.appendChild(document.createTextNode(start.concat(' - ', end)));
        time.classList.add("cstm-fc-time");
        el.appendChild(time);
    },
    eventPositioned: function(info) {
        let el = info.el;
        let parent = el.parentElement;
        if (info.event.extendedProps.event_type === 'placed') {
            if (el.classList.contains("fc-start")) {
                parent.removeAttribute("colspan");
                parent.setAttribute("colspan", "1");
            }
            if (el.classList.contains("fc-end")) {
                let columnNumber = parseInt(parent.getAttribute("colspan")) + 1;
                let endDateColumn = parent.parentElement.querySelector("td:nth-child(" + columnNumber + ")");
                parent.classList.remove("fc-event-container");
                parent.removeAttribute("class");
                parent.removeAttribute("colspan");
                parent.childNodes.forEach(function(item) {
                    let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
                    endDateColumn.appendChild(clone);
                    endDateColumn.classList.add("fc-event-container");
                    endDateColumn.setAttribute("colspan", "1");
                    el.remove();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```